# How to get an array of matches and misses using regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract anything between two square brackets, whilst keeping non-matched strings, up to the point of the next match, in an array.

For example:

`var string = "Keep [[this]] and [[this too]]";
// Some code
// output = ["Keep ", "this", " and ", "this too"];`

What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: `"Keep [[this]] and [[this too]]".split(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/)` is close (you'd just have to remove the trailing empty string).

Comment: Is there anyway I can know which items within the array were matches and which were not?

Comment: Yes, the elements at odd indices are matches.

Comment: How do you know odd matches were certainly enclosed with brackets? @melpomene

Comment: @revo Because that's how split works?

Comment: Are you talking only about OP sample? @melpomene

Comment: @revo See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split): *"If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array."*

Comment: This code `"Keep [[this]] and [[this too]]".split(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/)` output is `["Keep ", "this", " and ", "this too", ""]` that's similar to what OP desires. However, having a bit modified version of latter string, this code `"Keep [[this]] and that and [[this too]]".split(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/)` outputs `["Keep ", "this", " and that and ", "this too", ""]` which is not what OP desires: `["Keep ", "this", " and", "that , "and ", "this too", ""]` @LucasTrzesniewski

Comment: @revo Why do you think that's not what OP wants?

Comment: @revo looks like that's exactly what OP expects.

Comment: Then at this point I think there is need of more clarification.

Comment: @revo No, I think you just need to read the question.

Comment: I didn't talk to you. @4castle

Comment: *What's the fastest way to do this?* Wouldn't you prefer to first find a way that works, then worry about how fast it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a regex with a capturing group does this:

```
var string = "Keep [[this]] and [[this too]]";
string.split(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g)
// Array ["Keep ", "this", " and ", "this too", ""]
```